# Upgrade one Google Apps for Business account to paid while keeping the others free

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

I’ve got an old Google Apps for Business account with about 10 email addresses running Gmail and one of them is near the 15GB limit. Is it possible to just upgrade that one to paid (to get more space) whilst leaving the others as free accounts?

Comment: You upgrade entire Google apps for business accounts, not individual email addresses

Comment: Thanks Sathya, so does that mean i can upgrade 1 of my 10 accounts ie 1 user in Google Apps (all the features, docs, gmail, calendar etc..) OR do you mean i have to upgrade all my accounts all 10 of 10

Comment: while you can't upgrade one account, you can add more storage to that account. refer my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the Google Apps upgrade is [for the entire domain](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3035792?hl=en&ref_topic=29157), not individual email accounts *in* the domain.

However, what you can do is [add storage for just one user](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047457?hl=en&ref_topic=1727149) - login as the user, click on [Buy storage](https://www.google.com/accounts/PurchaseStorage) & select the plan that you want